# How to remove duplicate highs and lows

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to remove duplicates of the maximum and minimum values from a collection of integers. I can delete if there is 1 duplicate, but how can I remove when collection contains more then one?

```
values.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
           .skip(1)
           .sorted()
           .skip(1)
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
           .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Use a set to remove duplications.

Comment: but set remove all duplicate, I need only max and min

Comment: you can use `values.stream().remove(aNumberButNotAnObject )` and it will remove the duplicates too . Also it's not good to sort stream 2 times if you wont use it , you need to use the typical min/max algorithm .

Comment: Your stream operation does not “remove … from a collection of integers”. It’s creating a new collection of integers. In fact, since you immediately chained a printing operation, your operation is effectively only printing numbers without a persistent effect. You should be clear about your actual goal. The term “1 duplicate” makes no sense in the context either. If there’s only one value, there is no duplicate. So apparently, you don’t mean “duplicates” but “all occurrences” of a value.

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider you have `List<Integer> asList = Arrays.asList(2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8);`

You can create 2 different streams for your solution. First you will have to find out `min` & `max` using following way:

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = asList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).summaryStatistics();
```

This will return you min & max. Once you get both the value you can try to filter out the record and collect all the remaining.

```
List<Integer> collect = asList.stream()
                              .filter(x -> x > stats.getMin() && x < stats.getMax())
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
collect.add(stats.getMin());
collect.add(stats.getMax());
```

You will get the required output once you sort the list: `[2, 4, 6, 7, 7, 8]`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> numbersList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8));
    Collections.sort(numbersList);
    int min = numbersList.get(0);
    int max = numbersList.get(numbersList.size() - 1);
    numbersList = numbersList.subList(numbersList.lastIndexOf(min), numbersList.size());
    int maxIdx = numbersList.lastIndexOf(max);
    while (maxIdx != -1) {
        numbersList.remove(maxIdx);
        maxIdx = numbersList.lastIndexOf(max);
    }
    System.out.println(numbersList);
```

o/p: `[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7]`